# how do i create this specific diagonal array with eye() in numpy

Tags: numpy

How can I create an array below using `eye()` function?
I thought `eye()` only produced 0 and 1

```
[[2, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 1],
 [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Happy Yoon: you should show appreciation for answers that help you by upvoting them or marking them as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.eye(3,3)
b = np.eye(3,3,k=1)
c = np.eye(3,3,k=-1)

diagonal_array = 2*a+b+c

print(diagonal_array)
```

Or

```
diagonal_array = 2*np.eye(3,3) + np.eye(3,3,k=1) + np.eye(3,3,k=-1)
print(diagonal_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using broadcasting:

```
n = 3
v = np.arange(n)

out = n-1-abs(v[:,None]-v) # or n-1-abs(np.subtract.outer(v, v))
```

output:

```
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

with `n=7`:

```
array([[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       [4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 3],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: @HappyYon so you always want to generate 3x3 arrays? Using multiple eye of not very practical.